# Debug Maven goal in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, debugging, selenium-webdriver, maven-failsafe-plugin

I want to debug a maven goal, so, unlike testng or junit, i dont have option to bedug an maven goal which executes the pom.xml file, i have seen some posts available in stackover flow, but, those are not clear, they are discussing about some remote debug with post as 8000,which need to be run after executing the maven goal with argumenst as -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8000, when i try these, i am getting some error  as below. please some one, give me steps to execute my selenium tests in debugging mode
[image]

Comment: Start your tests via IDE and instead of running just use debugging?

Comment: No that not working, i have tried with debig configuraions  , but the ocntrol is not stopping at beak points

Comment: For some reasons which I don't know, I had to clear all the breakpoints before attaching and it works for me.